# Open file by default application flutter

Tags: android, flutter

How to open a file by default application using flutter?
For example, I have a .txt file and want to open it using the device's default application.
I think that there should be something like Process.Start() from .Net.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[open_file](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/open_file#-readme-tab-) plugin helped, nevermind.

---

Update from Vishnu Haridas comment:

> open_file has unnecessary permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES and your app can get rejected from Google Play if the target API level is 30 (Android 11 R). An alternative solution is to use open_file_plus or url_launcher.

Comment: `OpenFile.open(filePath);`

Comment: does it work with doc/docx ? in my case it opens pdf but not doc files.

Comment: I haven't tried with the .doc file, but it works with xlsx.
But what happens when you try to open .doc? Are you sure that there's an application for .doc files on the phone?

Comment: `open_file` has unnecessary permission **`REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`** and your app can [get rejected from Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779) if the target API level is 30 (Android 11 R). An alternative solution is to use `open_file_plus` or `url_launcher`.

Comment: Seems like this is a new restriction, I'll add in my answer

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/open_app_file claims to fix these issues.

Answer (score 3):

[open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file/versions) plugin didn't worked for me.

And that's where [Android_Intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent/example) came to rescue.

In my case the meme type was video. And that's why following snippet seems to be working.

```
String path = "your_local_file_path";

final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
        action: 'action_view',
        data: Uri.encodeFull(path),
        type: "video/*");
intent.launch();
```

Update: [addroid_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent/example) has been *discontinued and replaced with the community package* [android_intent_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus)