# Dart - How to Open File in Outside Application

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to give an application the ability to open a certain file in another outside application. For example, if a user attempts to open a .pdf file that is listed in my application, they will be redirected to an application they have installed on their device. How am I able to do this? Is there a library that gives me this ability or is this something I must work out myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) package
and specify the path

```
OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.pdf");
```

Supported paths

```
{
            {".3gp",    "video/3gpp"},
            {".apk",    "application/vnd.android.package-archive"},
            {".asf",    "video/x-ms-asf"},
            {".avi",    "video/x-msvideo"},
            {".bin",    "application/octet-stream"},
            {".bmp",    "image/bmp"},
            {".c",      "text/plain"},
            {".class",  "application/octet-stream"},
            {".conf",   "text/plain"},
            {".cpp",    "text/plain"},
            {".doc",    "application/msword"},
            {".docx",   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"},
            {".xls",    "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
            {".xlsx",   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
            {".exe",    "application/octet-stream"},
            {".gif",    "image/gif"},
            {".gtar",   "application/x-gtar"},
            {".gz",     "application/x-gzip"},
            {".h",      "text/plain"},
            {".htm",    "text/html"},
            {".html",   "text/html"},
            {".jar",    "application/java-archive"},
            {".java",   "text/plain"},
            {".jpeg",   "image/jpeg"},
            {".jpg",    "image/jpeg"},
            {".js",     "application/x-javascript"},
            {".log",    "text/plain"},
            {".m3u",    "audio/x-mpegurl"},
            {".m4a",    "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {".m4b",    "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {".m4p",    "audio/mp4a-latm"},
            {".m4u",    "video/vnd.mpegurl"},
            {".m4v",    "video/x-m4v"},
            {".mov",    "video/quicktime"},
            {".mp2",    "audio/x-mpeg"},
            {".mp3",    "audio/x-mpeg"},
            {".mp4",    "video/mp4"},
            {".mpc",    "application/vnd.mpohun.certificate"},
            {".mpe",    "video/mpeg"},
            {".mpeg",   "video/mpeg"},
            {".mpg",    "video/mpeg"},
            {".mpg4",   "video/mp4"},
            {".mpga",   "audio/mpeg"},
            {".msg",    "application/vnd.ms-outlook"},
            {".ogg",    "audio/ogg"},
            {".pdf",    "application/pdf"},
            {".png",    "image/png"},
            {".pps",    "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"},
            {".ppt",    "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"},
            {".pptx",   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"},
            {".prop",   "text/plain"},
            {".rc",     "text/plain"},
            {".rmvb",   "audio/x-pn-realaudio"},
            {".rtf",    "application/rtf"},
            {".sh",     "text/plain"},
            {".tar",    "application/x-tar"},
            {".tgz",    "application/x-compressed"},
            {".txt",    "text/plain"},
            {".wav",    "audio/x-wav"},
            {".wma",    "audio/x-ms-wma"},
            {".wmv",    "audio/x-ms-wmv"},
            {".wps",    "application/vnd.ms-works"},
            {".xml",    "text/plain"},
            {".z",      "application/x-compress"},
            {".zip",    "application/x-zip-compressed"},
            {"",        "*/*"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a duplicate but a really close question to the one asked by [Ruben Martirosyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8343248/ruben-martirosyan)

Quoting the answer of [Tushar Pol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5407008/tushar-pol) :

> open_file plugin didn't worked for me. And that's where Android_Intent came to rescue. In my case the meme type was video. And that's why following snippet seems to be working.
>
> ```
> String path = "your_local_file_path";
>
> final AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
>         action: 'action_view',
>         data: Uri.encodeFull(path),
>         type: "video/*");
> intent.launch();
> ```

[Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042321/open-file-by-default-application-flutter)