# How to open and view any network file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to open and view network files, i.e. pdf, ppt, doc, docx, and mp4 within the app (if possible without downloading to temporary directory). What is the best approach to achieve flutter?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open file by default application flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042321/open-file-by-default-application-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can ust use the following code,

```
window.open(
  url,
  '_blank',
);
```

This will open the URL in a new tab, or you can use respective widgets like [assets_audio_player: ^3.0.4+3](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) for audio and etc,.

Comment: The OP did not specify whether this is a web application. It might as well be a phone application or a desktop application. How is this going to help?

Comment: One could simply use https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher